# Change underlying database in visual studio c# datasets

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, dataset

I'm not sure whether or not my question sounds stupid, but I currently have an issue with a database project (MySQL with MySQL .Net connector for Visual Studio) and c#. When working on the live server, the project is working pretty fine, but as I want to continue developing on a staging system, I need to change all the database connections to a new database server. I thought it might be as easy as changing the connection string, but it is not.
Even when searching the whole project folder for the IP address of the previous server and replacing it with the staging server's IP address, the dataset designer still has some references to the original server and refuses to make changes.
Is there any recommended way to simply change the underlying database system withouth having to rewrite the whole software project?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: You should set the connectionstring once in the app.config or web.config of your project and use the name of that connectionstring throughout the entire solution. That way if you need to change it, you will only have to change it in one place.

Comment: I thought so, but it does not work that way. The software is running fine, but as soon as I want to make changes to the datasets using the dataset designer, I see an error message saying that no connection can be made to any of the database servers.

Comment: In you xsd files you will also have to make sure that the connectionstring is set to the one in the web config. Something like this: `DbSource ConnectionRef="DbConnectionString (Web.config)"`

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! If you had given that as an answer, I would have marked it as correct :-) Thank you!